# is it possible to pull code from expired scratch org in salesforce

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I need to pull some of my code form scratch org but scratch org just expired and i did not take the pull of of my code.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it is not possible, the scratch org is useless after expiration, so it's strongly recommended to run pull command often and make sure you have local copy of your org with latest updates.

Comment: Also is better to have GIT repository setup and make frequent commits.

Comment: is it some thing salesforce can do, if i raise a case ?